# brownie UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2127: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, unicode, brownie

I tried to compile my contract using brownie and got the following error:

File "C:\Users\muvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2127: character maps to

I wanted to compile this contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract compileError {
    string[13] unicodeValues = [
        "&#x20;",
        "&#x2588;",
        "&#x2665;",
        "&#xac;",
        "&#x2d8;",
        "&#x5e;",
        "&#x58;",
        "&#x25d4;",
        "&#x25d5;",
        "&#x273f;",
        "&#xca5;",
        "&#x25c9;",
        "&#x2686;" //" ", "█","♥","¬","˘","^","X","◔","◕","✿","ಥ","◉","⚆"
        //could think about adding flowers &#x2740; ->❀ but we have already flowers
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the problem (couldnt imagine this...):

even if the ascii values are in the comment it cant compile. If I remove the comments, so the code looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract compileError {
    string[13] unicodeValues = [
        "&#x20;",
        "&#x2588;",
        "&#x2665;",
        "&#xac;",
        "&#x2d8;",
        "&#x5e;",
        "&#x58;",
        "&#x25d4;",
        "&#x25d5;",
        "&#x273f;",
        "&#xca5;",
        "&#x25c9;",
        "&#x2686;"
    ];
}
```

it compiles without any errors. Hope this is helpful for anyone with the same problem